# when starting mongod.exe, getting error of missing api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll

Tags: mongodb

when starting mongod.exe on windows 7, getting error

> "The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. 
>   Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. ".

After  installing VC ++ .net framework and vc_redist.x64, but still no luck. Any ideas how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 8):

First install Window Update KB2999226 or download it from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows) according to your OS. then install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 redist (vc_redist.x64 in your case). Restart the pc and run mongodb files(mongod or any).

Answer (score 3):

Download Visual C++ Redistributable from

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145

After installation, try to rerun mongo.exe.