# when starting mongod.exe on windows 7, getting error

Tags: mongodb

when starting mongod.exe on windows 7, getting error

"The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. ".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to your Windows update. You have to update your current Windows(here Windows 7) version until no updates available.

First, install Windows update **KB2999226**. Then install **Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 redist** (vc_redist.x64 or vc_redist.x32). Restart the PC and run MongoDB **mongod**.

**Please follow these links:**

[api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing when opening Microsoft Office file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-opening-microsoft-office-file)

[when starting mongod.exe, getting error of missing api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43165669/when-starting-mongod-exe-getting-error-of-missing-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0)

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27606?jql=Participants%20%3D%20hotcola